# Selecting Properties from Property_Features list

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two SQL tables:

```
PROPERTY
PID  Address
1   123 Center Road
2   23 North Road
3   3a/34 Crest Avenue
5   49 Large Road
6   2 Kingston Way
7   4/232 Center Road
8   2/19 Ash Grove
9   54 Vintage Street
10  15 Charming Street

PROPERTY_FEATURE
P.PID  Feature    
1      Wine Cellar
1      Helipad
2      Tennis Court
2      Showroom
7      Swimming Pool - Above Ground
9      Swimming Pool - Below Ground
9      Wine Cellar
```

I want to Select the properties which contains specific features. For example, I would like to select the property ID which has the features Wine Cellar and Helipad, it would return the Property with the ID of 1.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you made any effort to do this yourself? We're not a homework completion or code writing service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using `Group By` and `Having` clause

```
select PID 
From PROPERTY_FEATURE
Group by PID 
Having COUNT(case when Feature = 'Wine Cellar' then 1 end) > 0 --1
   and COUNT(case when Feature = 'Helipad' then 1 end) > 0 -- 2
```

1 ) `Counts` only when `Feature =  'Wine Cellar'` & `> 0` will make sure atleast one `'Wine Cellar'` exist for each `PID`

2) `Counts` only when `Feature =  'Helipad'` & `> 0` will make sure atleast one `'Helipad'` exist for each `PID`

`AND`  will make sure both 1 & 2 is satisfied then return the `PID`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by filtering on the required features, and then grouping and counting in a HAVING clause. You could also group directly (without filtering first) but if the table is very large, with many pid's, that will result in a lot of unnecessary grouping of rows that won't be used in the end.

Something like this:

```
select pid
from   property_feature
where  feature in ('Wine Cellar', 'Helipad')
group by pid
having count(feature) = 2;
```

This assumes there are no duplicates in the table (so you can't have `1 'Helipad'` twice, messing up the count). If there *can* be duplicates, change the last line to `count (distinct feature) = 2`.

Comment: But the drawback is, the solution becomes less flexible when you move the filter to `Where` clause. Though for current question your answer is perfectly fine

Comment: @prdp - I don't see it. If there are more features, they go into the IN list, instead of the HAVING clause. Right?

Comment: Consider you want to find the `PID` which has only  `'Wine Cellar'` & `'Helipad'` then you have to remove that where clause and handle it in Having..

Comment: @prdp - Why? What is wrong with filtering so only the rows with `Wine Cellar` and `Helipad` even make it to the grouping stage? Perhaps I am missing something, but I don't understand what. Are you sure you understand my solution? Or do you mean homes that have ONLY those features and no others? If so, I don't believe that was the requirement.

Comment: I said for current question your solution is perfectly fine.. I just altered the requirement like I want to find the `PID` which has **only** `'Wine Cellar'` & `'Helipad'` in it.. Never mind.. Just my view and suggestion :)

Comment: @prdp - No, OK, now I understand what you mean. You are right, if the requirement is to also be able to exclude certain features, than my solution wouldn't work without significant changes. Fair enough.